# c# How to find duplicate records in a dataset that contains many datatables?

Tags: c#, datatable, duplicates, dataset

I have a DataSet that contains many DataTables (at least one table, could be much more).  Is there a simple way to check the entire DataSet for duplicate records?
By duplicate, I mean:
Each table represents a Student object, and has three columns: StudentId, StudentName, and NumberId (in this project, Students can belong to Numbers).  I need a way to see if the same Student exists in two or more tables, that is, does the same StudentId show up in multiple rows of any of the tables?
I have tried --

```
protected void CheckForDuplicateStudents()
{
DataSet setStudents = new DataSet();
foreach (GridViewRow gvr in grdNumbers.Rows)//grdNumbers on html page
    {
        int numberId = int.Parse(grdNumbers.DataKeys[gvr.RowIndex].Value.ToString());

        //for each row in the grid, get the student enrollent as a dt
        //put each dt into the dset
        DataTable tblRoster = PerformanceAccess.GetStudentsInNumber(numberId);

        setStudents.Tables.Add(tblRoster);
    } 

var duplicatedRowsExist = dsetStudents.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                           .GroupBy(r => r, DataRowComparer.Default)
                           .Any(g => g.Count() > 1);`

//do stuff here if query returns any duplicate records
}
```

But as I understand it, this LINQ query (and similar) only checks for duplicated values *within* a single datatable, not across all the tables in the set.

Is there a direct way to do this?

EDIT -- I should clarify, each table will have multiple rows, where each row represents a Student

`

Comment: I don't understand your configuration. The purpose of a _table_ is to store multiple records with the data that defines the entities (more than one) you want to store there. I have understood that you have multiple tables and each table stores a single student record. Is that right?

Comment: @Steve - Sorry if this was unclear -- each table will have multiple Students in it.  If it's relevant, the dataset represents the entire roster of a Performance, which has multiple Numbers inside it, and each Number can have many Students.  (Performance > Numbers > Students)

Comment: Why store students across multiple tables at all?  If there is some difference like school year or class that can be easily represented by a new column or attribute.

Comment: @Nyssa - I added more code above, I hope that makes it more clear.  The tables are fetched based on rows of a gridview

Comment: What you say is, you have multiply tables with the exact same structure. This is very unusual. Putting the same student in multiple tables in the same Database is not normalized data.

Comment: @Holger - Yes, the same Student may show up in multiple tables, in the sense that the same Student can belong to several different teams (Numbers, in this case).  But all Students are stored only on the Students db table.

Comment: This is a contradicting statement. You say "stored ONLY in Table student" AND "show up in multiple tables". Either one or the other can be true. Nobody ever needs to find duplicates, cause nobody is going to store duplicates. Maybe you should provide sample data. If a Team is identified by a number, then why putting different Teams in different tables ? you would put all student-team relations in one table only. That's all so contradicting.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit scant on detail, but if we work to a set of assumptions:

- You have a dataset with N tables
- All tables have a StudentID column of type int
- You want to detect particular ints that have been repeated

The following code will leave you with a List that cites all the repeated rows:

```
HashBag<int> idx = new HashBag<int>();
List<DataRow> dupRows = new List<DataRow>();

foreach(DataTable dt in dataset.Tables)
{
  foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
  {
    int sid = (int)dr["StudentID"];
    if(idx.Contains(sid))
      dupRows.Add(dr);
    else
      idx.Add(sid);
  }
}
```

DataRows have links back to the table they live in, so if you need reference to the datatable a particular row inhabits, call e.g. `dupRows[0].Table`

If you want the first row as well as all the duplicates of it, consider a Dictionary instead:

```
Dictionary<int, DataRow> idx = new Dictionary<int, DataRow>();
List<DataRow> dupRows = new List<DataRow>();

foreach(DataTable dt in dataset.Tables)
{
  foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
  {
    int sid = (int)dr["StudentID"];
    if(idx.Contains(sid))
      dupRows.Add(dr);
    else
      idx[sid] = dr;
  }
}
```

Now the dictionary contains the first encountered row, and the list contains all the duplicates of it

Comment: Thanks very much!  Your assumptions are correct, I should have made that clearer in my question. I'll implement this.

Answer (score 0):

hi you can use (distinct methode)

```
var duplicatedRowsExist = dsetStudents.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().GroupBy(r => r, DataRowComparer.Default).Any(g => g.Count() > 1).distinct()
```